# gpsd_client generating no data with artificial nmea file

Tags: ros, gpsd-client

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everybody,

I'm currently developing a **gps-based** ROS application using **ros-kinetic** on Ubuntu 16.04. For the time being, I have no access whatsoever to a real gps device. Instead I'm using the toolkit included in the linux **gpsd-clients** package for simulating it with a given log file, like so:

```
gpsfake -c 0.1 -P 4000 gps_log.nmea
```

This command creates a gpsd server and feeds the contents of the log file as if they were produced by a real gps device. I can verify it's working by using this next command:

```
gpsmon localhost:4000
```

which connects to the gpsd server and shows proper positioning information.

However, when I launch the ROS **gpsd_client** node:

```
<node name="gpsd_client" pkg="gpsd_client" type="gpsd_client" args="_host:=localhost _port:=4000" respawn="true" />
```

I can make it work (produce messages on the `/fix` topic) **with only 1 specific log file** that I have found on the internet. I cannot see the difference between that working log file and the ones I create using tools like this one: https://nmeagen.org/. This tools generates RMC, GGA and GSA sentences, which I believe should be enough. Actually, one difference I see is that the working log has plenty of different sentences (GSV, VTG, and others), but I don't know if there are some mandatory ones or maybe I'm missing something silly. I can attach the nmea files if necessary.

I need this to work with generated log files. If you now anything I could try with this approach, any workaround, or any other way to achieve this I would really appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270322/gpsd_client-generating-no-data-with-artificial-nmea-file/) by [mescarra](https://answers.ros.org/users/31804/mescarra/) on ROS Answers with karma: 20 on 2017-09-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2017-09-07**:
Do you see a gps fix in e.g. cgps?

**Comment by [mescarra](https://answers.ros.org/users/31804/mescarra/) on 2017-09-07**:
Yes, just like with `gpsmon` I get Lat,Lon,Speed and Heading, and it reads: **Status: 3D FIX**

**Comment by [mescarra](https://answers.ros.org/users/31804/mescarra/) on 2017-09-07**:
Ok, I have just found the cause of it. By default, `gpsd_client` ignores gpsd feeds with a nan **epx**. When launching the node, a param called *check_fix_by_variance* can be set to *false* in order to generate navsatfix and gpsfix messages anyway. ^^

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-07-30**:
@mescarra could you write up your solution as answer and accept it?

**Comment by [mescarra](https://answers.ros.org/users/31804/mescarra/) on 2018-07-31**:
I don't have enough points to accept my own answer :s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok, I have just found the cause of it. By default, `gpsd_client` ignores gpsd feeds with a nan **epx**. When launching the node, a param called `check_fix_by_variance` can be set to **false** in order to generate `navsatfix` and `gpsfix` messages anyway. ^^

---

Originally posted by [mescarra](https://answers.ros.org/users/31804/mescarra/) with karma: 20 on 2018-07-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0